# Why is Minecraft not launching from my batch file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So I'm having this problem where I'm trying to start Minecraft from a batch file, but everytime I run it, it gives me this error message, "Windows cannot find 'minecraft.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again." but what's bothering me is that it has worked fine on my Windows 7 computer.

Here's the code that I used to start Minecraft:

```
if %input3% == 1 start minecraft.exe
```

My specs: Windows 8.1, 64-bit, 8GB RAM, 1TB hardrive.

Any help would be great!!

Comment: This batch file needs to be executed from the folder with `minecraft.exe` in it.  Or you need to add `minecraft.exe` to your path variable but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: You might need to do path/to/minecraft.exe

Comment: I've tried the path one before and it didn't work. Can I just create a new folder and put minecraft.exe in it so that it will work?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not in any way specific to Minecraft, and the question would be just the same trying to start any other program.

Answer (score 3):

This batch file requires that minecraft.exe be in the %PATH% environment variable, or more likely, in the exact same location as your minecraft.exe file is at. Chances are  you wanted to tidy things up and put minecraft elsewhere and have this batch file on your desktop or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line :

```
set %path%=%path%;<location of minecraft.exe>
```

And it will work.

Comment: Why will this work?  Expand your answer a bit.

Comment: Because you need to TEMPORARILY add minecraft folder to path, so it could search `minecraft.exe` in that folder and open it.

Comment: So add that to your answer.  Although, the way you have it, it's going to keep adding Minecraft to the path everytime you run it.